# Cordova iOS error: Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: ios, cordova, xmlhttprequest, cors, cordova-plugins

I've upgraded my Cordova iOS app to the latest versions:

```
iOS 4.1.0
Cordova  6.0.0
```

And I've updated the plugins and also added the new WKWebView Engine plugin.

I've added my Content-Security-Policy to the index.html file:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; img-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' data:;connect-src 'self' https://mydomain/myservice/; plugin-types application/pdf">
```

My config.xml always contained:

```
<content src="index.html" />
<access origin="*" />
```

but I added

```
<access origin="*.mydomain.*" />
```

for good measure.

I control the webserver the app is trying to connect to, and I have enabled CORS on it:

```
<httpProtocol>
    <customHeaders>
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
    </customHeaders>
  </httpProtocol>
```

The server has a valid SSL certificate and all the calls to it are https://.

My plist in xCode has:

```
Allow Arbitrary Loads : Yes
Exception Domains
    [mydomain]
        NSIncludesSubdomains : Yes
        NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads : YES
        NSTemporaryExceptionMinimumTLSVersion : TLSv1.1
```

I am building and running the app directly on to a device and using Safari Develop to view the error.

*I have an Android version of this app, with its own updated base code, which works fine.*

My further research indicated that it is the new WKWebView Engine plugin which is causing the problem. But the only suggestions I found about that are within Ionic forums, and I'm not using Ionic for this build.

Just to confirm, these are the error messages I'm getting from Safari in debug:

```
[Error] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 405 (Method Not Allowed) ([my thing], line 0)
[Error] Failed to load resource: Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. ([my thing], line 0)
[Error] XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://[mydomain]/[my service]/[my thing]. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

Comment: it seems that CORS is not correctly set on the server. Do your request has auth headers?

Comment: No. I was missing something. Added it in the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@jcesarmobile was correct. Simply adding the `httpProtocol` to my `web.config` wasn't enough. I also had to add the following code to `global.asax Application_BeginRequest`:

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
    If HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod.Equals("OPTIONS") Then
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, PUT, DELETE")
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Accept")
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1728000")
        HttpContext.Current.Response.End()
    End If
```

Answer (score 11):

Try this solution:

Search the code for the following line: (might be in several files, so do it for all of them)
`WKWebViewConfiguration* configuration = [[WKWebViewConfiguration alloc] init];`

And add the following two lines after it:

```
[configuration.preferences setValue:@TRUE forKey:@"allowFileAccessFromFileURLs"];
[configuration setValue:@"TRUE" forKey:@"allowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs"];
```

Comment: This works like a charm. Could you explain the root cause? I am not a iOS native app developer. Thanks a lot.

Comment: is it possible to do this using config.xml?

Comment: since this is the only way to make it work, how can this be put in config ?

Answer (score 0):

This answer saved me without modify code.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/66444794/6606354

> Additionaly, WKURLSchemeHandler support has been introduced with this release. Using a custom scheme to serve your app content through fixes CORS issues that exist because of the strict security policies that WKWebView has applied to the file scheme. You can easily configure your Cordova project to use a custom scheme by setting the preference options scheme and hostname in the config.xml file.

```
<preference name="scheme" value="app" />
<preference name="hostname" value="localhost" />
```

doc here: https://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2020/06/01/cordova-ios-release-6.0.0.html