# iOs - Cordova - HTTPS - What is the best way for app to get the SSL certificate?

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, ssl, https

What is the best way to get the self-signed SSL certificate used by an iOS Cordova app for local dev, so that I can test HTTPS connections to my server-side app? On Android Cordova it's adding it manually to the `res` folder.

My SSL certificate is already imported as a profile to the iOS device.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you already have imported the certificated on the device you can simply enable it as trusted certificate in system settings ( I think it was Settings -> General -> About -> Certificate trust settings).

Comment: Did that too, but then I receive the following error when connecting Web Inspector to my app: ```Failed to load resource: The certificate for this server is invalid. You might be connecting to a server that is pretending to be "10.0.2.2" which could put your confidential information at risk```. If I access this IP via Safari, it connects without issues though, hence certificate is properly trusted.

Comment: Then most likely the root CA certificate or the leaf certificate you use has an issue.

Comment: Well, the certificate is accepted by Safari on iOS and on Chrome and the app itself on Android, so I'd say the problem should not be on certificate's side. Maybe in the iOS app itself I have to import it somehow, or is it imported directly if your device trusts the certificate?

Comment: To my knowledge when you install a certificate on iOS and trust it it will be accepted by secTrustEvaluate in every app. So unless your app uses a modified TLS certificate validation checking it should be accepted.

Comment: I still think the Cordova app is not "taking" the certificate properly. I imported the CA and the certificate again, installed both of them and trusted the CA, but it does not change anything. However, Safari connects to the server-side IP. Maybe some plugin I may need? For now I only have ```barcodescanner```, ```dialogs``` and ```inappbrowser```. Also, using ```<preference name="scheme" value="http" />
  <preference name="hostname" value="10.0.2.2" />``` as stated in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64060290/cordova-ios-origin-null-is-not-allowed-by-access-control-allow-origin-on-local

Comment: Also restarted the app, the iPhone 13 and xCode - nothing changed